# Compare key value array in ejs to combo selected value

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have a route js where I define get function like this:

```
exports.get = function (req, res) {
var calls = [{

    propertyTypes: function (acc) {
        return '/catalog/propertyTypes/';

    },

}];

    commercial_residential = {
        1 : 'Residencial',
        2 : 'Comercial'
    }

    property_types = [
        [
            [4  , "departamento"],
            [5  , "campo"],
            [8  , "casa"],
            [13 , "duplex"],
            [43 , "casa"],
            [47 , "departamento"],
            [49 , "campo"],
            [50 , "Terreno"],
            [53 , "departamento"],
            [63 , "ph"]
        ],[
            [1  , "Local"],
            [2  , "Quinta"],
            [3  , "Cochera"],
            [4  , "Galpon"],
            [5  , "emprendimiento"],
            [6  , "Lote"],
            [7  , "Oficina"],
            [9  , "Fondo de Comercio"],
            [10 , "Galpon"],
            [12 , "fondo de comercio"],
            [13 , "fondo de comercio"],
            [79 , "fondo de comercio"]
        ]
    ]

fetcher.getWithDependencies(calls, function (err, results) {
    var propertyTypes = (results.propertyTypes) ? results.propertyTypes : [];
[];

    fetcher.get('/ilist/importer/get/property/' + id, function (e, results) {
        res.render('ilist-importer/property', {
            'data': results,
            'list': {
                'propertyQR': propertyTypes,
                'propertyTypes': property_types,
            }
        });
    });
})
};
```

In my form for this get function, in ejs file I have a combo where I display all `property_types` names. When forms submit I need to compare that selected value property_type name with key value array `propertyQR` that comes from route.js.
Here's my form select:

```
   <select name="comercial" id="comercial_form" class="span3">
              <option value="0">-Seleccione-</option>
                <% for(var i=0; i < list.propertyTypes[1].length; i++) { %>                            
                   <option value="<%= list.propertyTypes[1][i][1] %>">                          
                     <%= list.propertyTypes[1][i][1] %>
              </option>
                    <% } %>
                </select>
```

Here's what I have so far. First I try to copy PropertyQR array that I get from route.js into a new array PropertyTypeID, and then when form submits I compare selected value in form with the key value array name field that I created and get id field if it matches.

```
  <script>

        $(function () {
  var propertyTypeID = [];

  for(var i=0; i< <%= list.propertyQR.length%>; i++){

            propertyTypeID.id.push(<%= list.propertyQR[i].id %>)

            propertyTypeID.name.push(<%= list.propertyQR[i].name %>)

            };

 $('#submit-import-form').click(function(){
    for(var i=0; i < propertyTypeID.length; i++){

                if (tipoPropiedad==propertyTypeID[i].name)

                    propertyTID=propertyTypeId[i].id;

                }
}
  });

    </script>
```

Now, when I try to load the form I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Why is this happening? Please help!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that the EJS code is running on the server and it generates the client-side JavaScript code, which runs entirely separately without knowledge of your EJS environment. You can see what EJS generates by looking at what's returned to the browser.

This code has several problems:

```
var propertyTypeID = [];

for(var i=0; i < <%= list.propertyQR.length%>; i++){

        propertyTypeID.id.push(<%= list.propertyQR[i].id %>)

        propertyTypeID.name.push(<%= list.propertyQR[i].name %>)

        };
```

`propertyTypeID` is an array, it doesn't have `id` and `name` properties so they'll be `undefined`. Further, that variable `i` is defined in the client, not in the server-side EJS, so code like `<%= list.propertyQR[i].id %>` won't have access to the value of `i` that's declared just above it. Typically this would throw an error because `i` is not declared but you also declare a server-side variable called `i` in your second code sample, which I'm guessing is the `i` being used here.

I think what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
var propertyTypeID = [];

<% list.propertyQR.forEach(function(property) { %>
    propertyTypeID.push({
        id: <%- JSON.stringify(property.id) %>,
        name: <%- JSON.stringify(property.name) %>
    });
<% }); %>
```

Whether this loop is necessary at all I'm not sure. You may just be able to use `var propertyTypeID = <%- JSON.stringify(list.propertyQR) %>` instead. It depends on what exactly you're trying to do.

There are other problems, such as the comma in `propertyTypeID,length`.